# PHP created Main page with selection of Download two options related to Mysql Table fail to properly export file

Tags: php, download, directory, include

The below code is in the main page with two types selection. It has a user session login check with an *else* clause:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
   <select name="type">
      <option value="Technical">Technical Records</option>
      <option value="Spares">Spares Records</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Download Record"></input>
</FORM>

<?php
include(ABS_PATH . "/hidden/access.inc");
   if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
      if (isset($_POST["type"])) {
        switch ($_POST['type']) {
            case "Technical":
                 include(ABS_PATH . "/hidden/export.php");    
                 break;
            case "Spares":
                 include(ABS_PATH . "/hidden/export.php");
                 break;
        }         
    } else {
        echo "please select download option";        
    }
} else {
    echo "Please Login First"; 
    function redirect($url) 
    {
        ob_clean();
        header('Location: '.$url);
        ob_end_flush();
        die();
   }
   redirect('login.php');
}        
?>
```

The sub download page has PHP code to download from a specific table, where its name is included in with the Database connection username, db name, pass Table name etc.

One of the two sub-pages for download are as below code:

```
<?php
//session_start();
//define("ABS_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
//include '/hidden/access.inc';
include(ABS_PATH . "/hidden/access.inc");

//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   

} else {

   function redirect($url) 
   {
    ob_clean();
    header('Location: '.$url);
    ob_end_flush();
    die();
    }
    redirect('login.php');
}
?>
```

For some reason the included sub-directory page, when calling the download, will include the main page HTML code when downloading in the dostorted export.XLS file.

Note:

1. I am in the 1st week of learning PHP. I have searched but couldn't find what could have possibly gone wrong.
2. **.htaccess** makes local access only on */hidden* to avoid direct access to the folder without having session set, so include option seems the only secured method to download from the */hidden* folder.

Comment: Welcome to SO. One advice is, as you just start PHP, you should read up-to-date tutorials, and, as mysql_* was deprecated in PHP 5.5 (please refer to [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)) you should **really** consider using [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will help [Preventing SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Then, make use of `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your pages.

Comment: Also, you should get rid of `@` as it will hide some very useful informations.